# What items do I need to play MvM?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I keep getting whined at because when I play scout I don't use the Mad Milk and when I play Soldier I don't use the Buff Banner. It's not like I don't *want* to use them, I just don't *have* them!

**What non-stock weapons do people expect me to have and use** in TF2 Mann vs Machine?

Comment: I smell something fishy here

Comment: Isn't it going to cause problems that you can't accept your own answer?

Comment: @murgatroid99 eh, it's not that I _can't_, it's that if I did I'd be abusing the voting system. (I can't merge my sockpuppet with myself on my own because I have too much reputation.)

Comment: Wait, are you doing this to abuse the voting system on purpose so you can merge your sock with your main account?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Nope, we were checking how the new users restrictions of 9- rep users interacted with editing posts. (They don't. You can't put images or 3 links in an answer, but if somebody puts those in for you then you can still edit the post.)

Answer (score 5):

This is what people expect you to use, especially when you Mann Up:

- Scout

  - **Mad milk**: when upgraded, slows enemy by 35%
  - **Fan O' War/Sandman**: the enemy you last hit with this weapon will take minicrits (increased damage) for a while. (Note: the Sandman must be upgraded using 500 points to gain the minicrit effect, but is then much more useful as you can hit enemies with baseballs from far away.)
- Soldier

  - **Buff banner**: when you deal damage a bar fills on your screen. When the bar is red switch to the banner (press 2) and click. You and players near you will deal minicrits. When your rocket launcher is fully upgraded, you can get the buff banner going in as little as three rockets. You should be using your banner as often as possible.
- Engineer

  - **Wrangler**: use to boost your buildings' health and fire rate at the cost of automatic aiming plus a three second sentry deactivation time when you switch to other guns.
- Sniper

  - **Jarate**: throw at enemies. Soaked enemies take minicrits and, with an upgrade, are also slowed down.
- Medic

  - **Kritzkrieg**: the ubercharge makes your patient deal critical hits (×3 bonus damage)
- Spy

  - **Dead ringer**: the instant-on cloak and the 90% damage reduction that comes with it makes you a tough nut to crack without having to spend thousands on credits on resistances.
- All classes

  - **Canteen**: lets you spend money for four-second buffs. Guaranteed critical hits are the most expensive and popular canteens, but instant ammo refills are also very good (and a fraction of the cost). Engineers always want to have at least one instantaneous building upgrade canteen.

You can obtain the canteen by completing any Mann vs Machine mission. You can get everything else from any scrap banker such as [scrap.tf](http://scrap.tf).

People may also expect you to use the following, although you probably won't get berated as much if you don't:

- Demoman

  - **Scottish resistance**: sticky jumping is harder but you can lay down more stickies at a time, useful when combined with kritz ubers at setup time to lay down a nasty initial surprise for  bots and tank.

Comment: You forgot about sappers.  Getting a bunch of bots to slow down is incredibly important.

Comment: @Retrosaur Sappers aren't unlockables.

Comment: But your question is "What items do I need to play MvM?" not "What do I need to unlock to play MvM?"

Comment: @Retrosaur thereifixit

Comment: I notice that there are no mandatories for Pyro, Spy and Heavy in that list...

Comment: @Shadur That's because Pyro and Heavy IMHO can use their stock items and be perfectly effective, whereas (say) a Soldier with a shotgun is very much less credit to team than a Soldier with a Buff Banner. As for Spy, I forgot about the dead ringer; fixing that.

Comment: Heavy with a shotgun isn't necessarily that effective.  Having a Sandvich on hand can help medics or any other class that is low on hp for an instant 50% hp fill

Comment: @Retrosaur thats a good point, and I was thinking of adding it when I added the Sandman,  but heavy is manly played for his Minigun in MvM.  His secondary doesnt make much of a difference regardless of what it is

Comment: Should I add the battalion's backup? It's far more uncommon in MvM, but  it's incredibly helpful when you have waves of mighty soldier robots with crits coming at you.